# CacheDuration for C# webmethod using web.config

Tags: c#

Is there a way to configure the CacheDuration attribute of a webmethod using web.config?
So I can change its value by just editing the web.config file anytime, without rebuilding the dll.
I am using C# .Net4.0
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a variable for that property? Does that work? If yes can you change that property and does it make use of the new value?